# Scope of "this" when defining functions inside sub-objects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scope, this

I'm extending a Backbone View with custom options about a footer which I evaluate in another class.

It looks like:

```
var EditUserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    footer: {
        name: "Hello",
        label: function() {
            //Return "Create" if it's a new model without id, or else "Save"
            return this.model.id ? "Save" : "Create"; 
        }
    }
});
```

As you see, a property should be able to be defined as either function returning a string or a normal string value.
I evaluate these options in the FooterView using _.result:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    //"options" is the footer-object from the view.
    this.data = {
        name: _.result(options, "name"),
        label: _.result(options, "label")
    };
}
```

But the problem is that I don't have access to the this of EditUserView inside the label-function I defined above. I also can't define a `var that = this`because I'm extending the object with no place for local variables.
How can I make the functions I define inside the footer-object have the this-scope of UserEditView?

I would also be okay with:

```
footer: {
    name: "Hello",
    label: this.getName
},

getName: function() {
    return this.model.id? "Save":"Create";
}
```

If the other way is not possible or this way is easier to do.

Comment: Can you use .bind(this)?

Comment: If you tell me where to call it in my example, I see no reason not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, `this` inside a function depends only on how the function is called (unless of course you have a bound function). Given this:

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    m: function() { console.log(this) }
});
var v = new V;
```

then these do different things:

```
var f = v.m; f();
v.m();
```

They're calling the same function but `this` in the first case will be whatever the global object is and in the second case it will be `v`; the difference is not in the function itself, the difference is in how it is called.

If we look at [`_.result`](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.5.2/underscore.js#L1108), we can see how it calls the function:

```
_.result = function(object, property) {
  if (object == null) return void 0;
  var value = object[property];
  return _.isFunction(value) ? value.call(object) : value;
};
```

Note the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) in there, that means that saying `_.result(obj, 'm')` is, if `m` is a function property of `obj`, the same as saying:

```
obj.m()
```

Applying that to your:

```
_.result(options, "label")
```

we see that you are effectively saying:

```
options.label()
```

and `this` inside the `label` function will be `options`.

I mentioned bound functions up above. The official way to create a bound function is to use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The **bind()** method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

That means that you can use `bind` to specify what `this` is inside the function regardless of how the function is called. You can also use [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind), [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll), [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), and various other methods for simulating the native `bind` method on functions.

In your view's `initialize`, you could bind the functions in `footer` to the appropriate `this`. But beware, you'll have to clone the whole `footer` to avoid accidentally sharing things through the prototype:

```
initialize: function() {
    var footer = {
        name: this.footer.name,
        label: this.footer.label.bind(this)
    };
    this.footer = footer;
}
```

That generalizes in the obvious way using whatever combination of [`_.clone`](http://underscorejs.org/#clone), [`_.isFunction`](http://underscorejs.org/#isFunction), and an iterator makes you happy.

The downside to that is that every instance of your view gets its own distinct copy of `footer` and that might be wasteful if you have a lot of instances or if `footer` is large. If this is a problem then you could write your own version of `_.result`, something like this (untested code):

```
_.mixin({
    i_cant_think_of_a_good_name_for: function(object, property) {
        if(object == null)
            return void 0;
        return _.isFunction(property) ? property.call(object) : property;
    }
});
```

and then say:

```
_.i_cant_think_of_a_good_name_for(this, options.name);
_.i_cant_think_of_a_good_name_for(this, options.label);
```

in your view. Note that the first argument here is the `this` you wish to use for the function and that the second argument is the whole property rather than just its name.